# How can i search in a formula and make some changes in string parts with perl

Tags: regex, perl

Hi i want to extract sub strings from a formula and make some changes to them later and put them back something like this:

```
((dfhkuyhu.hkjgd.hjkh + hgdfjg.uyrepo.uyu + hgdfjg.uyrepo.uyu)/(hgdfjg.uyrepo.uyu))*((khuh.jbmxcn.bnb + hgdfjg.uyrepo.uyu)/(jhxzku.kjkj.jh + hgdfjg.uyrepo.uyu))
```

and i want to add something tobeginning and end of each part like this:

```
((Foo!dfhkuyhu.hkjgd.hjkh![hg] + Foo!hgdfjg.uyrepo.uyu![hg] + Foo!hgdfjg.uyrepo.uyu![hg]).[boo]/(Foo!hgdfjg.uyrepo.uyu![hg]).[boo])*((Foo!khuh.jbmxcn.bnb![hg] + Foo!hgdfjg.uyrepo.uyu![hg]).[boo]/(Foo!jhxzku.kjkj.jh![hg] + Foo!hgdfjg.uyrepo.uyu![hg]).[boo])
```

any idea?

Comment: In order to have a chance of providing an answer let alone an approach, please post the actual formulas.

Comment: well what is the difference? it is some sets of characters with dots in between the structure of formula is exactly same as what i wrote and for now i'm spliting by '/' and '*' and '+'and storing then eliminating the parentheses then i will replace them and search the string and replace again but i'm still working on it i needed some ideas to solve it.
and i think the whole idea behind regex is matching patterns not having the exact formula right? formula can change but the pattern is same!!

Answer (score 2):

The rules are a bit unclear, but it seems you're trying to surround each run of alphanumeric characters (plus separating dots) with `Foo!`/`![hg]`, and to replace each closing parenthesis with `).[boo]`. Right?

Then you could do this:

```
$subject =~ s/[\w.]+/Foo!$&![hg]/g;
$subject =~ s/\)/).[boo]/g;
```

**Explanation:**

`s/abc/def/` means "substitute whatever the regex `abc` matches with the replacement string `def`", modifying the original `$subject` variable.

`[\w.]+` matches strings like `dfhkuyhu.hkjgd.hjkh`. In the replacement string, `$&` refers to the matched text. The `/g` flag tells Perl to find and replace all the matches in the string.

`\)` matches a literal parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks exactly that did the job i was doing it with lots of loops and headache Thanks

Comment: @AshkanAbdnkhn: Good to hear it - seems I have guessed correctly, then. In order to further improve your StackOverflow experience in the future, please take a few minutes to read Jon Skeet's excellent primer [How to ask the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). Welcome to the community!

Comment: thank you it was my firs question will do that in future and can you tell me how can i add the same suffix to the end of string as well because at the end there is no * to check it what i changed your code in was this
$input =~ s/\)\*/\).[boo]\*/g;
$input =~ s/\)\//\).[boo]\//g;
which misses the last one at the end of the string